# Remove space between 2 panel after transform 1 panel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm doing transform left menu (red color), but after I transform it, the right panel is not full space. How can i remove it?

> **When left menu transform finish I want right panel full and don't have
>   white space .**

Here is my code :

**Xaml file**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0"
                         To="-50"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Name="MyGrid" Background="Red">

            <DockPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </DockPanel.RenderTransform>

            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10" 
            Content="Click"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        </DockPanel>

        <DockPanel Background="Gold" Grid.Column="1" Name="test">

        </DockPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs file:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void showTopMenu_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Storyboard myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TestStoryboard"];

                TranslateTransform myTranslate = new TranslateTransform();
                myTranslate.X = 50;
                myTranslate.Y = 0;
                MyGrid.RenderTransform = myTranslate;

                Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(0) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);
                //Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(1) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);

                myStoryboard.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve here. Why do you think that Grid columns should change their widths just because you are setting a RenderTransform on their content?

Comment: Have you heard of the `GridSplitter` seems like that could help ya. I guess you try to resize 2 areas ..

Comment: @Clemens,  I think I set width = * in grid column 2 ,so when column 1 move I have a space, why grid 2 don't fill it :( . Please help me thank you

Comment: @motivated I want column 1 like left menu with animation, so I use transform and story board to hide a part of column. Unfortunately column 1 is hide but have a space, column 2 don't fill it :( . Please give me a recommend.  Thanks

Comment: You don't actually "move" (or resize) a column by putting a RenderTransform on the elements in the columns. Try to remove the Width from the first column (set it to "Auto"). Then set the Width of MyGrid and replace the RenderTransform by a LayoutTransform.

Comment: The Problem is that you are using `DockPanels` replace them with `Grid` and it should size without any animations. Set `Width` of the parent Grid to auto. On Button_Click change the value of one of the child grids widthproperties. The parent should resize to give the childs the space they need

Comment: Can you write the answer under here . I try both way but don't change anything :( . Thanks

Comment: @jonny, is it mandatory that Column 2 have a relative size, and not a fixed one, like Column 1 has?

Comment: @LupuSilviu Yes,it is you can fix it :(